# Audio initialization is fine but SDL_GetNumAudioDevices(0) reports 0 devices - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl-2

Audio works without a problem on Ubuntu 20.04 but SDL2 fails to use audio device while initialization is fine. On Ubuntu 18.04 it works like expected. On both installation SDL2 was compiled from source code (2.0.12).

This is the code example:

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"


int main(void)
{
    if (SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0)
        SDL_Log("SDL fails to initialize audio subsystem!\n%s", SDL_GetError());
    else
        SDL_Log("SDL Audio was initialized fine!\n");
    
    SDL_Log("Number of audio devices: %d\n", SDL_GetNumAudioDevices(0));

    SDL_AudioSpec want, have;

    // Set required audio specs
    want.freq = 44100;
    want.format = AUDIO_S16SYS;
    want.channels = 2;
    want.samples = 1024;
    want.padding = 0;
    want.callback = NULL;
    want.userdata = NULL;


    device = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &want, &have, 0);

    if (device == 0)
        SDL_Log("Failed to open audio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
SDL Audio was initialized fine!
Number of audio devices: 0
Failed to open audio: No such audio device
```

Comment: Of course you have updated sdl2 to the latest version.

Comment: 2.0.12 like Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The package for Ubuntu seems to be 2.0.10.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=sdl2&searchon=names

Comment: Maybe you don't know that it is possible to compile source code...

Comment: Maybe you edited that into your question so it wouldn't look like you were wasting everyones's time.

Comment: @stark I wrote: "2.0.12 like Ubuntu 18.04", never wrote "Last available Ubuntu package". In order to avoid people like you, that answer on a question only for increase the number of replies on stackoverflow, today I added the version on the OP post. Stop trolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. On new Ubuntu 20.04 installation **libasound2-dev** library is missing. It is necessary to install it before compile SDL2 from source code.

It is odd that audio initialization was fine also when the driver is not present